# How do I get a Unix Timestamp in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to know what the current timestamp is.  The best I can do thus far is define my own function that does this:

```
(int (/ (.getTime (java.util.Date.)) 1000))
```

Is there a standard function for fetching the Unix timestamp with clojure?

Comment: Don't use `int`: `(int (/ (.getTimeInMillis (java.util.GregorianCalendar. 2038 1 20)) 1000)) ;=> IllegalArgumentException Value out of range for int: 2150258400`. Try `quot` instead, e.g. `(-> (java.util.Date.) .getTime (quot 1000))`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Pretty much all JVM-based timestamp mechanisms measure time as milliseconds since the epoch - so no, nothing standard** that will give seconds since epoch.

Your function can be slightly simplified as:

```
(quot (System/currentTimeMillis) 1000)
```

** [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) might have something like this, but pulling in a third-party library for this seems like overkill.

Comment: Thanks, math cleanup aside `(System/currentTimeMillis)` is much more clear.

Answer (score 20):

I'd go with [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time), the standard Clojure library for dealing with times and dates (wrapping [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)). Yes, it is an extra dependency for a simple need and may be overkill if you really only want the current timestamp; even then it's just a nice convenience at virtually no cost. And if you do eventually come to need additional time-related functionality, then it'll be there with a great implementation of all the basics.

As for the code, here's the Leiningen dependency specifier for the current release:

```
[clj-time "0.15.2"]
```

And here's a snippet for getting the current timestamp:

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as time]
         '[clj-time.coerce :as tc])

;; milliseconds since Unix epoch
(tc/to-long (time/now))

;; also works, as it would with other JVM date and time classes
(tc/to-long (java.util.Date.))
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely a good solution if you're doing significant time calculations.

Answer (score -3):

```
(defn unix-time-real
  "Taken from
  System/currentTimeMillis."
  []
  (/ (System/currentTimeMillis) 1000))
```

Comment: This will return a ratio, while you probably want an integer. See Alex's answer.